# Вход в MySQL в консоли Ububtu под root

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

У меня несколько одинаковых по настройкам VDS Ubuntu 16.04.
На первом залогинившись под root в SHH-клиенте (Putty) набираю

```
root@local:~# mysql
```

и вхожу в эту СУБД без ввода пароля.

На других VDS таким же образом в mysql не входит - пишет:

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

Если  ввести

```
mysql -u root -p
```

а затем набрать пароль mysql-root-a, то входит.

Воспрос: Почему на других VDS нужно вводить пароль, а на первом -нет?

P.S. На всех VDS пароли root-ubuntu и root-mysql различаются.

Comment: «одинаковых по настройкам» — очевидно, не одинаковых)

Comment: Посмотрите содержимое таблиц mysql.user на каждом сервере, особенно столбец с плагинами

Comment: 1) Настройки на VDS абсолютно одинаковые (под копирку). 2) И там и там для всех пользователей в таблицах mysql.user стоит "mysql_native_password" в поле plugin

Comment: 3) для пользователей root-mysql в поле host задано "localhost"

Answer (score 1):

Нашел в чем причина:
Ранее изменял пароль root-mysql.
Поэтому, чтобы в консоли входить в mysql без ввода пароля, пароль root-mysql нужно прописать тут: /root/.my.cnf